# Rewriterule with parameter already indexed

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have a site with url like ref.php?id=2 already indexed by Google.
I know how add keywords in my url with these rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=2$
RewriteRule ^ref.php$ http://www.website.fr/boat? [R=301,L]
```

But, i don't know how redirect the old url to the new.
If i do this

```
RewriteRule ^boat$ /ref.php?id=2 [L]
```

I have an error.

The only solution i found is to duplicate ref.php into ref2.php
and adding this rule

```
RewriteRule ^boat$ /ref2.php?id=2 [L]
```

Maybe a better solution exist. So have you an idea ?

THanks

Answer (score 0):

Keep it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+ref\.php\?id=2[\s&] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /boat? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^boat/?$ /ref.php?id=2 [L,QSA]
```